# How do I solve NotImplementedError when using .groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe read from a `.csv` and I named it `df`:

[image: Dataframe contents]

I'm enrolled in this online academy, so I'm following what he does in the video. I was following his instructions on the video until he run this code

```
df.groupby('Attrition').agg('mean')
```

When I run it, it prompts an error; here's the error:

[image: fig.2 Error message]

The instructor on the video run the code and it works perfectly fine for him, here's his output:

[image: fig.3 Expected output]

They don't answer, they chat support because they have no people because this online academy laid off a lot of their employees because of their financial issue so no one answers our questions.

I'm using VSCode. I'm really new to this.

I'm using VS Code Jupyter Notebooks and I have all my required libraries all updated to the latest versions but it still won't work. I came across this raise `NotImplementedError()`, but I don't know how to use it.

Here's the dataframe raw data from Kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/whenamancodes/hr-employee-attrition

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




 df = pd.read_csv('path_hr_employee_attrition.csv')
 print(df.shape)
 df.head()


df.groupby('Attrition').agg('mean')
```

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: example dataframe would be helpful too...  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'll update my question then to add the dataset and the code I'm running. Really sorry not knowing that.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode